# mysql index creating issue

Tags: mysql, indexing, alter

I have deleted all the data from an existing table and then trying to alter table using the following query in mysql:

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX (created_on);
```

but nothing seems to working, it just keep running with out any result.

Comment: What does `SHOW INDEX FROM mytable` tell you after you have executed the ALTER statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct way to add an index:

```
create index idx_mytable_createdon on mytable(created_on);
```

Comment: Hence you use the `create index` statement as in my answer.